# Virtualbox - Error in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Im using `win10` and im trying to setup some VMs. However, the `Oracle VM VirtualBox` doesnt seem to work at all. Each time I try to start a VM in the VBox it says Error in `supR3HardenedWinReSpawn`

Is there a way to solve it? I tried both 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling virtualization on the bios and see if it helps if you haven't already.It worked on my windows 10 with virtual box Version 5.1.8 r111374 (Qt5.5.1)